# What is the Maximum Size of an Application(APK) to Download and Install Without WiFi in PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk, google-play-console, android-install-apk

I am currently part of an Application Development team. The size of our APK is around 96MB. I have heard that we can only download an application with a size less than 100MB without WiFi from the Google PlayStore. However, I couldn't find any official documentation stating the same. Some blogs say it as 100MB while some blogs say it as 150MB limit. I would appreciate links to some official docs from Google stating the limit. Also, since our application is almost on the line, will it be only available to download over WiFi if we cross 100MB?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to upload an apk, exceeding 100MB, to Google Play. It will complain.